What is a target scope of a static member definition?
int x = 42;
struct A {
  static int x; // 1
};
int A::x = x;   // 2

Why at 2 the redeclaration of x inhabits a class scope? Where is a locus of some declaration - only at the first declaration (1) or every redeclaration has its own locus (1 and 2)?

"Why at 2 the redeclaration of x inhabits a class scope?..." Because you wrtoe A::x meaning any name after that will also be searched in the class scope.

Not sure what you are asking. When you are in global scope, x is the global one and A::x is the class static one.

@wohlstad No, the second x in int A::x = x; is actually the static one.

Could you please provide a quote that explains why A::x is in a class scope and not in a global scope?

In // 2, you reenter the scope of the class at the point where A:: appears. From there, up to the ; at the end of the definition, you can use any of the names declared in the class.

@user12002570 I see. Is it because mentioning A::x brings us into class scope ?

@wohlstad Basically, the search lookup also uses the class named(which is A here) in addition to the global scope. It is because of the A::x

@tbxfreeware could you please provide a reference to the quote explaining this?

@wohlstad It(A::x) is very much relevant.

@user12002570 OK, then this makes more sense.

Not an answer to the question, but you can be explicit about the scope by using = ::x;.

@BoP the point of an unqualified name is to show that A::x is actually in a class scope, i.e. the name x later refers to the static member and not to the global variable

You misunderstood @BoP.

I cannot reproduce, https://godbolt.org/z/daaGqnT1E, which compiler and settings are you using?

See this answer in the dupe: Name Lookup and class scope

Why at 2 the redeclaration of x inhabits a class scope? Does it?

@Language Lawyer  Inside the class, global x is hidden by static x. You can access global x, but only if you scope to it: ::x. In the external definition of A::x, you reenter the scope of the class, which then extends to the ;, which terminates the definition. Within that scope, global x is, once more, hidden. To get to it, you must scope it. Otherwise, any appearance of x refers to the static variable defined with the class.

@tbxfreeware this does not require inhabiting the class scope

Sure. The priority for name lookup is the same as if you had reentered the scope of the class. If, for instance, there are base classes, or A is a nested class, those classes will be searched before considering the lexical scope of the external definition. I have always thought of this as "re-entering" the scope of the class, but if that's the wrong term, I stand corrected.

@cppbest Reopened.

@LanguageLawyer do you mean that "inhabiting the scope" is not the same as "being present in the scope"?

The target scope of A::x is the class scope of A because [dcl.meaning.general]/(3.4):

Otherwise, the terminal name of the declarator-id is not looked up. If it is a qualified name, the declarator shall correspond to one or more declarations nominable in S; all the declarations shall have the same target scope and the target scope of the declarator is that scope.

(Here S is the lookup context of A::x [dcl.meaning.general]/(3.1).)

This answer doesn’t explain why these two are different even though they seem the same: int A::x = x; and int A::x = ::x;.

@ChukwujiobiCanon https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#1.sentence-2

Still doesn’t answer my comment.

@ChukwujiobiCanon thats not OPs question.

@ChukwujiobiCanon • A::x and x refers to the x in the A scope.  ::x refers to the x in the global scope, rather than in the A scope.  That's why they are not the same.

@Eljay I know that. Read the answer again. The answer speaks to a different topic. The answer should have referenced another part of the standard not this. Anyways I rest my case.

That's the answer, thank you.
